# How to solve ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found?

Tags: oracle

I have the following procedure written in .Net that I'm trying to deploy to Oracle 18c

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Shared Function StoredProcedure1() As String
        Return "hi"
    End Function
End Class
```

I used Deploy feature on Visual Studio and the deployment was successful.

I configured **TNSNames.ora** as follows :

```
XE =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVER = DEDICATED)
   (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
  )
 )

LISTENER_XE =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SID = CLRExtProc)
   (PRESENTATION = RO)
  )
 )
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SID = PLSExtProc)
   (PRESENTATION = RO)
  )
 )
```

and **Listener.ora** as follows :

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
       (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
       (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
       (PROGRAM = extproc)      
    )
   (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Administrator\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )   
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.91.87.51)(PORT = 1521))      
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )         
  )
```

I created **OraClrAgnt** with default values :

```
oraclrctl.exe -new
```

The service was created successfully and running.

**TNSNames.ora** seems to be configured properly since when I check it using **TNSPing** the entries are resolved :

```
tnsping ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA
tnsping EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA
```

However when using the procedure in SQL I'm getting the error : **connection description for remote database not found.**

```
select STOREDPROCEDURE1 from dual;
```

Error :

```
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CLR", ligne 243
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CLR", ligne 42
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CLR", ligne 236
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.STOREDPROCEDURE1", ligne 6
02019. 00000 - "connection description for remote database not found"
```

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks

Here is the output of the command **lsnrctl services**

```
    Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.91.87.51)(PORT=1521)))
    Services Summary...
    Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
      Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
        Handler(s):
          "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
             LOCAL SERVER
    Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
      Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
        Handler(s):
          "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
             LOCAL SERVER
    Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
      Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
        Handler(s):
          "DEDICATED" established:469 refused:0 state:ready
             LOCAL SERVER
    Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
      Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
        Handler(s):
          "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
             DISPATCHER <machine: SVD5FD3, pid: 4564>
             (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=SVD5FD3)(PORT=49725))
    The command completed successfully
```

Comment: All this is running on the DB server? If you're using tnsnames.ora then you'll need to have $ORACLE_HOME or $TNS_ADMIN environment parameters set so that Oracle Client can find tnsnames.ora. Also, the "XE" entry is the only one in your tnsnames.ora that is valid for client connections - the others are only for internal use by the server; and "tnsping" only validates that the listener is available on the network port - it does not validate the actual service name or any of the other connection parameters.

Comment: @pmdba Thanks for your comment. Yes. Everything is running on the same machine and I have ORACLE_HOME variable set. So what I have to modify/add to tnsnames.ora please ?

Comment: for tnsnames.ora, it will depend on what you're trying to connect to. Is your database configured with a container (CDB) and pluggable database (PDB) architecture? What is the output of `lsnrctl services`?

Comment: @pmdba Thanks for your answer. I'm not trying to connect to anything specific at least as far as I know. I'm trying to use only my external procedure deployed to my XE database. Everything works fine except when I query the external procedure deployed. I'm getting ORA020-19 error. I added also the output of lsnrctl services.